# Get response by web api a json string and print only one of the values

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api, json-deserialization

I call an [API](http://api.icndb.com/jokes/random?firstName=Savas&lastName=Papa) that returns a JSON string like this one:

```
{ 
    "type": "success", 
    "value": 
    { 
        "id": 246, 
        "joke": "Random joke here...", 
        "categories": [] 
    } 
}
```

I want to make my program read the JSON string and return only the `joke` string. I was able to get the string from the Web API but I can't make it to JSON object so I can print only the joke string.

Comment: You could just use a placeholder instead of the real joke since you are posting the code at a Q&A network like this...

Comment: @FᴀʀʜᴀɴAɴᴀᴍ you were correct in editing the joke. the poster was linking to a joke api that returns random jokes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you'll need to create the classes to deserialize your json into. For this you can use VS's Edit -> Paste Special -> Paste Json As Classes or use a website like [JsonUtils](http://jsonutils.com):

```
public class JokeInfo
{

    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("joke")]
    public string Joke { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("categories")]
    public IList<string> Categories { get; set; }
}

public class ServerResponse
{

    [JsonProperty("type")]
    public string Type { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("value")]
    public JokeInfo JokeInfo { get; set; }
}
```

Then use a library like [JSON.NET](https://www.nuget.org/packages/newtonsoft.json/) to deserialize the data:

```
// jokeJsonString is the response you get from the server
var serverResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ServerResponse>(jokeJsonString);
// Then you can access the content like this:

var theJoke = serverResponse.JokeInfo.Joke;
```

Comment: Thank u very much to be honest the classes that json needs was my problem now that u pasted this site i think i fine !